# Ahorcado en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Hola buenas estaba haciendo un código donde hay que escribir un programa que comience leyendo en un vector una lista de palabras (máximo 25) y permita simular el siguiente juego:
El ordenador selecciona aleatoriamente una palabra de la lista y a
continuación el usuario intentará adivinar dicha palabra, letra a letra,
permitiéndose un máximo de ocho fallos.
Cada jugada o intento de adivinar una letra comenzará con un sorteo
del valor de la jugada (número aleatorio de puntos entre 1000 y 10000)
así como la presentación al usuario de la situación actual del juego
(letras y posiciones adivinadas, total de puntos, total de fallos).
Las palabras que van siendo adivinadas por el usuario son almacenadas por un vector pero no puedo lograr imprimir el vector con las letras de la palabra ordenadas.

```
import random
def valor(Valorjugada):
    Valorjugada = random.randint(1000,10000)
    return Valorjugada
  

Fallos = 0
Encontradas=0
Valorjugada = 0
Totalpuntos = 0
VectorEncontradas = []
Vectorcorrectas = []

Palabras = ["Auto", "Camion", "Argentina", "Teclado", "Living", "Cocina", "Brasil", "Lampara", "Pared", "Cortina", "Bicicleta", "Mueble", "Mesa", "Estadio", "Ventana" ]
Palabraseleccionada = random.choice(Palabras).lower()
VectorLetras = list(Palabraseleccionada) #lo mismo y mas eficiente
    
print(VectorLetras)


print("Debe adivinar la palabra")
while Encontradas < len(VectorLetras) and Fallos < 8: #mientras que tengas menos de 8 fallos o que hallas encontrado menos letras de las que hay en la palabra
    Letra = input("Introduce una letra :")
    if Letra in VectorLetras: #encuentra la letra en el vector
        print("Letra Encontrada")
        VectorEncontradas.append(Letra)
        
        for c in range(len(VectorEncontradas)):
        for i in VectorLetras:
            if VectorEncontradas[c] == VectorLetras[i]: #vector para colocar las letra que fueron adivinadas.
                resultado+= VectorEncontradas[i]
        print(resultado)
        
        Valorjugada = valor(Valorjugada)         

        print("El valor del jugada fue de: " + str(Valorjugada))
        Totalpuntos+=Valorjugada
        print("La puntuacion total es: " + str(Totalpuntos))
    else: #si no
        print("Fallaste")
        Fallos += 1
        print("Fallo numero: " + str(Fallos))
    if Fallos == 8:
        print("Cantidad de fallos excedida")
        print("fin del juego")
        break
```

Comment: Hola! Tal vez este video te pueda ayudar un poco https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2q6PUUDdRw

Answer (score 0):

Copié y pegué tu código así tal cuál lo subiste así que hago referencia a las líneas resultantes del copiado.

Primero debes corregir en la línea 28: for c in range(len(0,VectorEncontradas)): y quitale el 0 a la función len.

2do, tu problema es de lógica y en esto esta bueno que trates de llegar a la solución realizando debugs, etc. Pero te doy un tip importante, y es que en tu línea 29 (en tu comparación if) no estás permitiendo que el usuario coloque una letra y la misma se pueda encontrar en cualquier posición, y tampoco permitis que dicha letra esté presente más de una vez en el texto.
Lo que vos comparas con el bucle, es la posición 1 de VectorEncontradas con la pos 1 del VectorLetras, y así sucesivamente con todas las posiciones.

Por ende, sólo se cumple la condición en el caso de que el usuario esté colocando letra por letra en el orden específico de izquierda a derecha. Por ejemplo, si la primer letra de la palabra es "c", entonces hasta que el usuario no ingrese dicha letra no va a cumplirse la condición y por ende, tampoco se ejecuta la línea 30 (Vectorcorrectas = VectorEnocntradas)

Tu ejercicio no es simple, pero está bueno que trates de resolverlo porque serían problemas que día a día deberías enfrentar y resolver. Saludos

Comment: Intente recorrer el vector de la frase a adivinar junto con el otro vector donde se almacenan las palabras que ingresa el usuario en posiciones diferentes pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Punto 1, te recomiendo valorar las respuesta para generar interés en más personas, sino es más difícil que se detengan a contestar.
Punto 2, como decía un grande de youtube, "Si puedes imaginarlo, puedes programarlo". Cuando  tengas un problema así intenta imaginar cómo lo harías en la vida real, no con código, sabiendo que si recorres vector no ves la palabra entera sino que ves caracter por caracter.

Comment: Punto 3. Si no podes generar el código correcto, quizás debas tener un vector con la misma cantidad de caracteres pero con guiones por ejemplo. Cuando el usuario indicó una letra correcta le cambias el guión por la letra y así vas rellenando con los caracteres que sucedan. Cuando no hayan más guiones entonces es que se ha terminado con éxito el juego.

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta, si no vas a dar una solución está la zona de comentarios donde puedes guiar al usurio. Te recomiendo leer [answer].

Comment: Responder a la pregunta es hacerle el trabajo, y no creo que su objetivo sea que los demás le hagan el trabajo, él quiere aprender a programar con Python. Si no le ayudamos no estaríamos siendo útiles. Si él quiere le hago todo el programa y después que haga copy-paste, pero no va a aprender a resolver, sólo va a entender lo que yo le hice. Debe desarrollar el análisis y la resolución de problemas.
Distinto sería si su problema fuera error de sintaxis, uso de una librería, etc...

Comment: lo sé y por eso es que hay veces en que un comentario ayuda más que una respuesta. Si quieres hacer una respuesta debes hacer una buena y completa ;)